# Using html tags in asp file

Tags: html, asp-classic

hey im programing a little project website.

and i get a problem really annoying.

I'm writing the server-side pages in ASP, and i'm running it on babyweb server.

sometimes when i write HTML tags in asp file everything work properly.

but sometimes when i write HTML tags i get a problem, when i try to load the page its saying :

> Script error detected at line 0.
>   **Source line**: `Response.Write " "`
>   **Description**: Unfinished string constant

i guess its mean that i have to put `Response.write` on every html tag,

because when im changing the HTML tags to this

(for example, `<html>` to `<% Response.write "<html>"%>`).

what is that? maybe problem with babyweb server? there is a way to fix that?

thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code that cause the problem?

Comment: acttualy its all the page code there is not a specific lines. just when i write html tags, doesnt matter where . its saying that i have to put this in response.write.. i tried to remove the html tags and its work fine , but i need those tags .. so what should i do?

Comment: Can you maybe write a "Hello world" page that can reproduce the problem, and then post the code here, so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Sounds like really really poor web server. Just move to other server..

Answer (score 0):

In your example...

```
<% Response.write "< html>"%>
```

The spacing is wrong, try...

```
<% Response.write "<html>" %>
```

Note that I added a space before the closing tag... "%>"